# angular leaflet directive:: check if point is in polygon

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

So, I know that with leaflet I can check if a point is in a polygon (in my case just using the map view port) with:

```
    map.getBounds().contains(marker);
```

But I am not able to figure out how to do the same thing using angular leaflet directive, I am trying:

```
    $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.moveend',function (e, args) {
        leafletData.getMap().then(function(map){
            var bounds = map.getBounds();

            var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]);

            var foo = bounds.contains(marker);
            console.log("foo");
            console.log(foo); // returns: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
            // another try:
            //map.getBounds.contains(marker);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after looking around on github

```
    $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.moveend', function (event) {
        leafletData.getMap().then(function (map) {
            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            var foo = bounds.contains(L.latLng(51.5, -0.09));
            console.log("foo");
            console.log(foo);

        });
    });
```